How to map smb drive permanently in Kubuntu?
I'm not sure if i'm posting this question in the correct forum but here goes anyways.
I'm running Kubuntu VERSION="24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
with Samba version 4.19.5-Ubuntu
My laptop is running windows 8.1
. I can view a network drive through Dolphin using the smb://192.xxx.x.xx.
This part is easy but what i need to know is can i make this folder permanent?

Connect to the network drive using smb://192.xxx.x.xxx. Right click on the folder and select Add to Places. This will add it to the left panel of Dolphin. Again right click and Edit… — there You can change its label and icon. Source: Dolphin File Management

If the instructions above worked for you let me know in a comment. I will convert my comment to an answer so that you can accept it as correct. This will help others.
